# Assets.xcassets in iOS project for buttons image

Tags: ios, image, button, assets

Can I use Assets.xcassets in iOS project for buttons image or only for backgrounds and app icon?

In my universal application, I use Assets.xcassets to set images for background and app icons for all view sizes. Can I use that for any button or image view?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can store any type of image for any purpose in the `Assets.xcassets`.

You can read some further information on the [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_ref-Asset_Catalog_Format/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015170-CH18-SW1) portal about the Asset Catalog.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use it.

Go to assests.xcassets -> tap + button on the bottom left corner -> New image set.

Now change the set name and add 1x/2x/3x images (or pdf). You can find this picture by name in Interface builder or from code.

[image]